# Probability of intersection of events/independence.

Tags: probability

Suppose 15% of students speak French and 45% are women. Suppose also that 20% of the women speak French. A committee of 10 students is formed by randomly selecting students. What is the probability there will be at least 1 woman and at least 1 French speaking student on the committee?

A- french (15%)
B- woman (45%)
AB- both (20%)

So far, I have that it would be easier to solve this by using the complement.

P(at least 1 woman, at least 1 french)
= 1 - [P(at least 1 french, but no women) + P(at least 1 woman, but no french) + P(no women, no french)]

Not entirely sure how to calculate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look at $P(A\cap B)$ more carefully.  You have said that this is $20$%.  This means that $20$% **of the students** are French-speaking women.  However that's not what the question said, rather it said that $20$% **of the women** speak French.  So here are some **hints**.

(1) Find the correct value of $P(A\cap B)$.

(2) Using a Venn diagram, or otherwise, find the proportion of students who are not women and don't speak French.

(3) The committees that we **don't** want to count are those which consist entirely of people from (2).  So find the probability of this happening.  Note that presumably you need $10$ **different** people on the committee, and if this is the case the problem cannot be answered unless you know the total number of students.